# MongoDB Cross-db DBRef's in 2.4

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb

I'm running MongoDB 2.4.6 locally and the MongoDB PECL extension is 1.4.3 while testing this.

I'm currently working on an app that has two MongoDB databases, one called `nc_main` with a collection called `companies` and one called `nc_test` with a collection called `users`. I'm trying to set it up so a `companies` document can have a reference to a `users` document but it doesn't seem to be working for me. When I view the company document I see:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("xxxx"),
    "maintainer" : DBRef("users", ObjectId("yyyy"))
}
```

However the DBRef was setup in PHP using: `MongoDBRef::create('users', $user['id'], 'nc_test');`.

I can run the following query but it doesn't change what I see when I query the document: `db.companies.update({ _id: ObjectId("xxxx") }, { $set: { maintainer: { "$ref": "users", "$id": ObjectId("yyyy"), "$db": "nc_test"} }})`.

The problem this leads to is that attempting to load the `users` document via the reference results in a document not found error because it's looking in the `nc_main` database and not the `nc_test` one like I'm trying to tell it to.

Comment: No one but the actual PHP driver maintainers can answer this, you might be better going to the user group

Answer (score 1):

Note that the shell does not support the $db fieldname of MongoDBRef, which is why it doesn't show up there (and coming to think of it, it looks like a bug in the shell that it even convert the data into DBRef JavaScript object).

Also, MongoDBRef isn't anything other then a convention. It isn't magical and doesn't do any "auto fetching" or "auto expansion", it is just a convention that many people use to "link" documents within the same collection - and in some cases, across databases. Not all ODMs (or drivers for that matters) supports the $db fieldname though.

That being said, it is a nice convention - but I can't quite see what isn't working for you.
Could you show me how your "resolving" code looks like? (eg. retrieving the linked document).

As an example, this is the testcase I wrote up for this question and it seems to work fine locally on MongoDB 2.4.6 and PHP Driver 1.4.3

```
<?php

$mc = new MongoClient;
$companies = $mc->selectCollection("nc_main", "companies");
$users = $mc->selectCollection("nc_test", "users");

/*
$companies->drop();
$users->drop();
*/



/* Create a user in nc_test.users */
$user = array(
    "nick"  => "bjori",
    "title" => "Fixer",
);
$users->insert($user);

/* Create a reference to the newly created user */
$userref = MongoDBRef::create("users", $user["_id"], "nc_test");


/* Create a company in nc_main.copmanies */
$company = array(
    "name" => "MongoDB",
    "maintainer" => $userref,
);
$companies->insert($company);


/* Fetch the inserted company again, just to make sure the roundtrip didn't
 * modify the MongoDBRef in any way */
$mongodb = $companies->findOne(array("_id" => $company["_id"]));
/* Get the reference.. */
$maintainer = $mongodb["maintainer"];

/* Backtrac the database to select from by passing it as the first argument */
$bjori = MongoDBRef::get($mc->selectDb($maintainer['$db']), $maintainer);
var_dump($bjori);
?>
```

Results in:

```
array(3) {
  ["_id"]=>
  object(MongoId)#14 (1) {
    ["$id"]=>
    string(24) "528ab8c68c89fef7250041a7"
  }
  ["nick"]=>
  string(5) "bjori"
  ["title"]=>
  string(5) "Fixer"
}
```